# What law could Jack Sweeney have broken in automatically posting public flight information?

Tags: united-states, air-travel, stalking

[It is currently in the news](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-68223602) that Taylor Swift is threatening Jack Sweeney with legal action over his use of publicly available data to track the take-offs and landings of planes belonging to the wealthy and post them one day later.  [He has previously been threatened by Elon Musk](https://www.bracknellnews.co.uk/news/national/23192325.musk-threatens-legal-action-twitter-account-tracked-private-jet/) for the same thing, I THINK no law suit came from that.  I believe those tracked are chosen because they have a high carbon footprint from private flights.

What laws could Jack Sweeney have broken such that Taylor Swift and others whom he tracks could have a successful case against him?

Comment: The best source would be to read any pleadings from a lawsuit, but unless a lawyer finds some law, no law will be brought.

Comment: Swift's lawyer's letter to Sweeney makes various allegations although it only directly names one law. California Code, Civil Code - CIV § 1708.7.

Comment: Really? The **stalking** law? https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/civil-code/civ-sect-1708-7/ - I see

Comment: @Trish I'm not sure if it relates to that particular law, but in media reports it is implied that the issue isn't that the defendant stalked Taylor Swift himself, but that he enables other people to do so by making the information easily available to them.

Comment: A copy of the letter to Sweeney is here https://time.com/6692227/taylor-swift-cease-desist-letter-jack-sweeney-jet-tracker-emissions/. The second sentence seems to be claiming that Sweeney himself has "engaged in stalking and harassing behavior, including consistently publishing real-time and precise information about our Client’s location and future whereabouts to the public on social media."